# MySQL - Escaping ampersand (&) in fulltext searches

Tags: mysql, escaping, full-text-search

We are using a fulltext search to search for the name of a company and all is going well until we have a company with an ampersand in its name, e.g. 'M&S'.

```
SELECT name FROM company WHERE MATCH (name) against ('M&S' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This fails to return any results as MySQL is treating the ampersand as a boolean operator. The boolean mode is desired so it can't simply be turned off.

What I'm looking for is a way to escape the ampersand so that MySQL treats it correctly and finds the record.

Ditching fulltext search in favour of `LIKE`s isn't exactly an option either

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't see `&` listed as a special character in the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html. Are you sure it's not because `M&S` is too short to be indexed? See the `ft_min_word_len` option, it defaults to 4.

Comment: @Barmar ft_min_word_len is set to 2 as we have quite a few very short company names.

Comment: Another possibility is that `&` is treated as a word delimiter. So that's actually two words: `M` and `S` with punctuation between them.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html for how to change the characters that are considered part of a word rather than delimiters.

Comment: @Barmar I tried `set global ft_boolean_syntax = '+ -><()~*:""_|';` to remove the & from the syntax but that appears to have made no difference. Perhaps `Positions 10, 13, and 14 (which by default are set to “:”, “&”, and “|”) are reserved for future extensions` prevents that.

Comment: according to [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26265) changing that var is basically not supported, but a plug can be used to (allegedly) do what you want

Comment: And what is this plug(in?) that you mention @Plutonix?

Comment: Try replacing the amperstand with its code in unicode and escape that: `\U+0026`

Comment: @sqlab please see the second comment above

Comment: @ionutioio no joy with unicode I'm afraid.

Comment: @RobForrest how are you actually using this query? with a variable for the company name? or just the string?

Comment: Have you seen this. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26265 It is an old bug, but marked as won't fix, for your exact problem.

Comment: @JohnRuddell with a variable for the company name being searched for.

Comment: Have you tried removing the IN BOOLEAN MODE, seeing as for this particular search you don't need it, and there may be some strange interaction with ft_boolean_syntax. Just to rule it out.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes I have tried that too

Comment: @Rob Forrest, after changing ft_min_word_len and restarting MySql did you recreate the fulltext index too with **REPAIR TABLE company;**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `&` isn't considered a word character in the collation you use for your fulltext search.

so you have to **create your own collation** (or recompile your MySQL server) where you add `&` to the list of word characters like i found out in the MySQL docs (
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) :

> If you want to change the set of characters that are considered word
>   characters, you can do so in several ways, as described in the
>   following list. After making the modification, you must rebuild the
>   indexes for each table that contains any FULLTEXT indexes. Suppose
>   that you want to treat the hyphen character ('-') as a word character.
>   Use one of these methods:
>
> Modify the MySQL source: In myisam/ftdefs.h, see the true_word_char()
>   and misc_word_char() macros. Add '-' to one of those macros and
>   recompile MySQL.
>
> Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The
>   true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish
>   letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents
>   of the  array in one of the character set XML files to
>   specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for
>   your FULLTEXT indexes. For information about the  array
>   format, see Section 10.3.1, “Character Definition Arrays”.
>
> Add a new collation for the character set used by the indexed columns,
>   and alter the columns to use that collation. For general information
>   about adding collations, see Section 10.4, “Adding a Collation to a
>   Character Set”. For an example specific to full-text indexing, see
>   Section 12.9.7, “Adding a Collation for Full-Text Indexing”.

**UPDATE:** in case you are using latin1 collation, open your XML file which is at `mysql/share/charsets/latin1.xml`. and find the corresponding character code in a map - in this case you can take the map for lower case or upper case because this doesn't matter for the ampersand symbol:

```
<lower>
<map>
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F
 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F
 40 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F
 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F
 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F
 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F
 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 8B 8C 8D 8E 8F
 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F
 A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA AB AC AD AE AF
 B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA BB BC BD BE BF
 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA EB EC ED EE EF
 F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 D7 F8 F9 FA FB FC FD FE DF
 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA EB EC ED EE EF
 F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA FB FC FD FE FF
</map>
</lower>
```

the ampersand's unicode is `U+0026` and in utf-8 encoding it's `0x26`, so search for `26` in the map - which is in the 3rd row, 7th column.

then in the `ctype`-map change the type of the character from 10 which means punctuation to 01 which means small letter:

```
<ctype>
<map>
 00
 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 28 28 28 28 28 20 20
 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
 48 10 10 10 10 10 01 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 10 10 10 10 10 10
 10 81 81 81 81 81 81 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 10 10 10 10 10
 10 82 82 82 82 82 82 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 10 10 10 10 20
 10 00 10 02 10 10 10 10 10 10 01 10 01 00 01 00
 00 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 02 10 02 00 02 01
 48 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 10 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 02
 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 10 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
</map>
</ctype>
```

restart your MySQL server and the corresponding collation is handling `&` like it was a small letter.

of course it's better to first copy and rename your new collation `XML`-file and to also copy and paste the corresponding lines in the `Index.xml`  (don't forget to use a new unused id in the `XML` tags there) and link them to your new collation `XML`-file so you don't lose your original collation.

you can find the full documentation where i got most of the information from here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-text-adding-collation.html

Note - For all those working with Mysql 5.7 version use an unused collation id. The mysql article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html is for Mysql 5.5 version. To get maximum collation Id use following Query -

```
   SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS;
```

Comment: Wow! This might actually be a solution. Sadly I'm not really in a position to recompile MySQL to test this out, I hear its an absolute nightmare.

Comment: @RobForrest you don't have to recompile it, that's just one of the 3 available methods described here. look at the 3rd paragraph i quoted: `This requires no recompilation ... You can edit the contents of the array in one of the character set XML files to specify that '-' is a “letter.” `

Comment: I'd like to look more into modifying a character set but I have literally no idea where to start. All the documentation I can find is really wooly, do you have any examples?

Comment: That absolutely worked! Can you think of any knock on repercussions or complications that this might cause?

Comment: glad to hear that i could help you! in your custom collation `&` is now considered being a small letter, that's all you changed and this is only relevant for `full-text-indexing` as far as i know. so i don't think there will be any complications. but i'd still suggest to use your custom collation only where you need it.

Comment: Would you be so kind to someday update your answer/webpage to show how to do this for the same `&` character but using a UTF8 charset using `index.xml` and `rules` and `reset` ?

Comment: @ck_ I am sorry but I don't have the time for something like that in the moment. but doesn't this work quite similar anyway - just with different XML data?

Comment: As UTF8 is compiled it does not come with character set configuration file. You'll have to modify `true_word_char()` macro in [ha_innodb.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/eb1babefdc8cab2a9193324150f8349a45ecdd06/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L6061) and recompile MySQL or installing and configuring a standalone fulltext search software like SOLR or Sphinx may be a better solution.

Comment: @dušan-brejka You do not need to recompile mysql any longer to add a collation to a multibyte charset if the new collation is based on an exisiting already compiled in multibte collation, example here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ldml-collation-example.html

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** so the & is splitting it into two separate words... since they are 1 letter it is not returning anything. I tested with "Ma&Sa".. my ft_min_word_len = 4... and it didn't return anything so since the length of that string > 4 but its not returning it has to be splitting it into two words... it looks like the suggestion northkildonan made is what you have to do.

So this may or may not be an answer.. but I hope it is helpful for figuring this out.. try this.

first: run this statement -- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len';` and affirm that the length is actually = 2
if it is i'm not sure how it is any different than a word that is longer than a length of 4

Second: I did this and got results.

**SET UP:**

I set up a sample table on my localhost database...

```
create table company(
`id` int,
`name` varchar(55)
);

insert into company
(`id`, `name`)
values
(1, 'oracle'),
(2, 'microsoft'),
(3, 'M&S'),
(4, 'dell');
```

**TESTS:**
tested when ft_min_word_len = 4 and obviously it didn't return anything.

```
SELECT `name` FROM company WHERE MATCH (`name`) against ("M&S" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I didn't want to try restarting my localhost database to reset the length to 2 (incase I accidentally mess something up because I use it a lot)..

but I got the idea of trying to look for the name of a company that was longer than a length of 4 with the & in it.

**MORE SETUP:**

```
insert into company
(`id`, `name`)
values
(5, 'Mary&Sasha');
```

**ANOTHER TEST:**

```
SELECT `name` FROM company WHERE MATCH (`name`) against ("Mary&Sasha" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

this returned http://screencast.com/t/Rx8mh98OUp

I also did this just incase the collation was messing it up but I doubt that was the problem..

**COLLATION STUFF:**

```
ALTER TABLE company MODIFY
    `name` VARCHAR(55)
      CHARACTER SET latin1
      COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
```

you can also check your tables collation with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

hope this is at least some help :)

Comment: Thanks John but the company names are what they are.

Comment: I've now tried changing the character set too and that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @RobForrest I know the company names are what they are.. what I was trying to show is that the & does not seem to be a problem as that exact query works with 'Mary&Sasha' ... did you try running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len';`? because you have to restart the database to change the length

Comment: John, my minimum word length is 2. Setting it to 1 to fall in line with your example is not a sensible option.

Comment: @RobForrest I wasn't saying set it to 1.. that statement just shows what its set at.. 1 would not be sensible at all... i wonder why I don't have an issue with using it on `Mary&Sasha`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I made the same test, and I would say `Mary&Sasha` is interpreted as the 2 words `Mary` and `Sasha`. `&` is simply not taken in account. In our `M&S` case, it would result with `M` and `S` words. First, they **are** under 2 letters word length ; second, I'm not even sur MySQL accept single characters as words. I have not been able to deepen the test.

Comment: @zessx so the full text search matches Mary and also Sasha inside the one word "Mary&Sasha" which is why its coming back true? if thats the case I have another test for that

Comment: @JohnRuddell I still haven't put the finger on the problem, but that would be my assumption.

Answer (score -2):

`&` is not a special character in mysql therefore you are able to store and search for the expression `&`
you can test that as followed

```
    SELECT name FROM  `testing` WHERE name LIKE  '%&%'
```

also please try somthing like the following to replace the `&`.

```
    SET @searchstring = 'M&S';
    SET @searchstring = REPLACE(@searchstring,'&','&amp;');
    SELECT name FROM company WHERE MATCH (name) against (@searchstring IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

You may also take a look at regexp.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Here the & is used as followed.

```
    mysql> SELECT '&' REGEXP '[[.ampersand.]]';
```

The following query is also getting you the result

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `testing` 
    WHERE  `name` REGEXP CONVERT( _utf8 'M&S'
    USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

please also read this thread, maybe you can understand it better then me. This is SQL but they seem to have solved the problem
http://forums.asp.net/t/1073707.aspx?Full+text+search+and+sepcial+characters+like+ampersand+

sorry I couldn´t help more

Comment: This question is very specifically about fulltext searching, i.e. `Match (x) Against (y)` not `like` so your 1st and 3rd suggestions aren't really solutions. As for your second suggestion, that doesn't return the expected results as MySQL treats the & as a special character.

Comment: the OP specifically said that you can't use `LIKE` ... it does pull it out when using like which is a good example.. but the I think the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` makes the & a non escapable special character

Comment: regexp is a complex search tool and it was a suggestion. Normaly & is no special char, but what john said makes sense

Comment: yea its not a special character that mysql recognizes to escape... but it seems like the boolean mode does that. it seems like the OP is stuck using the MATCH ... AGAINST.. method, do you know of a way to work with that parameter?

Comment: Have you tried this?? "A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html